# Don't understand how mocked classes works when invoking methods

Tags: java, unit-testing, jakarta-ee, mocking, mockito

I have a class that have one getter like this:

```
public Animal get(int id) {
    final Animal animal = crudRepository.get(id);
    assetRepository.attachAssets(animal);

    return animal;
}
```

I want to create a simple unit test for this. I have mocked the `crudRepository` to always return a fixed animal. I have also mocked the `assetRepository` and set the mocked repository on the class that I want to test. However, I don't understand how it works, why don't I get nullpointers and errors when invoking the `attachAssets` method? It is has return type void. I mean, in the `attachAssets` method I use things that I never created (sessions etc.). Does Mockito automatically catch exceptions or something, is it something special for void methods or what? In other words, I haven't stubbed the `attachAssets` method of the `assetRepository` so why don't it fail (or should it even fail, I don't know)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mock is a dummy implementation. It's a subclass of the mocked class which overrides all its methods, and replace their implementation with alomst nothing (i.e. it returns what you tell it to return, throws what you tell it to throw, and records the invocations to be able to verify them after).

Here's some example class:

```
public class AssetRepository {
    public void attachAssets(Animal a) {
        // some real implementation
    }
}
```

And here's a simplified example of a mock implementation created by Mockito:

```
public class MockAssetRepository extends AssetRepository {
    private List<Invocation> invocations = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void attachAssets(Animal a) {
        // store the invocation to be able to chack if it has been called, 
        // how many times, etc.
        invocations.add(new Invocation("attachAssets", a);
    }
}
```

You see that whatever your implementation is, it's not called, because attachAssets() is overridden in the mock.

Answer (score 1):

if you mock the AssetRepository the methods are called on the mock and the actual implementation doesn't matter anymore. Instead Mockito uses a dummy version of the method (which does nothing).

The default behaviour for Mockito if you haven't told it anything else is to do nothing or return null/0, whichever is appropriate. It will usually only throw an exception if you tell it to. Other mocking frameworks might complain if you call some unexpected methods.

Comment: Ah, so there are empty methods when you mock, and the methods which have other return types return default values as specified in the API?

Comment: Be aware that the "default" return value of a mock's methods isn't always 0, false or null.  It can also be an empty collection, "" or 1, under some circumstances.  Check the documentation for more details.